# How to stop the preview server

Tags: node.js, wintersmith

This code is based on wintersmith static site generator

In my code I'm starting the preview server like this:

```
env.preview(function(error, server) {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log('Server running!');
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log("going to shut it down")
    server.stop();
  }, 3000)
});
```

This is taken from the example. I would expect the preview server to stop after 3 seconds, but instead I get an error, that server is undefined.

I looked a bit closer at it and indeed: server is undefined. Anything I'm doing wrong? How am I able to stop the preview server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug, create an issue on github and i'll have a look at it when i get some time.